# Converting a directory content into a json file

Tags: json

I have some files with `.txt` extension (in directory A) and I need to make a `json` file for this specific directory (A) from a different directory (B) in which the name and location of all the files should be included.
Do you know how I can do it with a bash script? (Then I want to use this `json` file for my data analysis).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how to do this entirely via a bash script, but if you have knowledge of Python, you could use the included `os` and `json` modules to list all the files in the directory, add them to a dictionary. Then create the JSON module using `json.dumps()`. Once you have written the script, you can invoke it via the bash shell.